# Can resharper generate tostrings that includes all of the classes properties?

Tags: c#, resharper, log4net

I use IntelliJ (java) IDE and it can easily generate a really nice toString() for any class that includes all the properties etc.

So in my log4net I want to output the deserialized version of a class.

Can resharper do this or do I have to manually do it myself?

Answer (score 10):

Yes it can. Look at help topic [Generating Formatting Members](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Formatting_Members.html).